Assigning user to a new group with "usermod -a -G" not persisting
On Ubuntu 22.04.
I have a user fred who has the default group memberships:
fred $ sudo -i
root $ id fred
uid=1001(fred) gid=1001(fred) groups=1001(fred),27(sudo)

I want to addthis user to the vboxusers group so I run:
root $ usermod -a -G vboxusers fred
Then:
root $ id fred
uid=1001(fred) gid=1001(fred) groups=1001(fred),27(sudo),141(vboxusers)

I then logout and back in as the user fred only to find the the user is not by default in this group:
fred $ sudo -i
root $ id fred
uid=1001(fred) gid=1001(fred) groups=1001(fred),27(sudo)

However when I check with getent I see the user is assigned that group:
fred $ getent groups | grep vboxusers
vboxusers:x:141:fred

Also if as fred I run newgrp vboxusers then check id I see the vboxusers group is present:
fred $ id
uid=1001(fred) gid=1001(fred) groups=1001(fred),27(sudo)

fred $ newgrp vboxusers
fred $ id 
uid=1001(fred) gid=1001(fred) groups=1001(fred),27(sudo),141(vboxusers)

But again, after logout and back in again, that group is gone from id fred.
Why is the group association not persisting when I log out?
UPDATE
I tried a remote SSH to the server as fred, and on that I found the vboxusers group present as expected in the id output. So it seems that logging out of the Ubuntu GUI session does not fully initialise the user settings, suggesting that a reboot is required. Surprising.

after usermod -a -G vboxusers fred does fred appear as a member of vboxusers in /etc/group

@JaromandaX yes it does. I just found that if I ssh into the server as fred the group is present. So it seems looging out of the GUI session and back in again is not fully initialising/refrshing  the user session.

it actually seems looging out of the GUI session is removing the user from the group - which is odd

Confirmed that rebooting the server persists the group addition. So how can we get the GU login to re-initialise fully without rebooting. I do not recall having this issue before either.

seems you need to logout/login - that's what I've always done when changing group membership - I don't use any GUI, so, not sure why that would be any different
